# Getting null in json passed via ajax (Spring)

Tags: json, ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I create a "musician" object on the client side and send it to the server using AJAX:

```
$("#add_musician_button").click(function() {
    var musician = {
        name: $("#musician_name").val(),
        photo: $("#musician_photo").val(),
        startYear: $("#start_year").val(),
        stopYear: $("#stop_year").val(),
        genres: genresList,
        countries: countriesList, 
        type: $("#musician_type_select").val(),
        frontman: $("#band_frontmen").val(),
        fullName: $("#solo_full_name").val(),
        birthYear: $("#solo_birth_year").val(),
        deathYear: $("#solo_death_year").val(),
        description: $("#description").val(),
        history: $("#history").val()
    }

    console.log(musician);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save_musician",
    data: JSON.stringify(musician),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert('Musician "' + response.name + '" successfully created!');
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("An error occurred while creating the musician!")
    }
    });
```

On the server, I accept it. To do this, I created a special class "musicianJson" in which I repeat the JSON object.

```
class MusicianJson {
    String name;
    String photo;
    String startYear;
    String stopYear;
    Set<String> genres;
    Set<String> countries;
    String type;
    String frontman;
    String fullName;
    String birthYear;
    String deathYear;
    String description;
    String history;
}

@RestController
public class AddMusicianRestController {

    @PostMapping("/save_musician")
    public ResponseEntity<String> AddMusician(@RequestBody MusicianJson musicianJson) {
        System.out.println("Musician name = " + musicianJson.name);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Musician received");
    };
}
```

Why do we need the "musicianJson" class? This is because the musician entity is associated with entities like "countries" and "genres", so I will have to get those objects first (according to user input) and add them to the new "Musicians" object . This is why I can't write `public Musicians AddMusician(@RequestBody Musician musician)`
So, In the server console I get the message: `Musician name = null`. Why?

Comment: I think the variable name in the client and server side should match. Try renaming the server variable to musician_name as well to test if it works. Actually, you should map musician_name to name using jackson.

Comment: If that is your full class you are missing getters/setters which are used by Jackson to set the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - add getters and setters for MusicianJson class:

```
class MusicianJson {
    String name;
    String photo;
    String startYear;
    String stopYear;
    Set<String> genres;
    Set<String> countries;
    String type;
    String frontman;
    String fullName;
    String birthYear;
    String deathYear;
    String description;
    String history;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }
    public void setPhoto( String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
    public String getStartYear() {
        return  startYear;
    }
    public void setStartYear( String startYear ) {
        this.startYear = startYear;
    }
    public String getStopYear() {
        return stopYear;
    }
    public void setStopYear() {
        this.stopYear = stopYear;
    }
    public Set<String> getGenres() {
        return genres;
    }
    public void setGenres( Set<String> genres ) {
        this.genres = genres;
    }
    public Set<String> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
    public void setCountries ( Set<String> countries )
    {
        this.countries = countries;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType( String type ) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getFrontman() {
        return frontman;
    }
    public void setFrontman( String frontman ) {
        this.frontman = frontman;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName( String fullName ) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public String getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }
    public void setBirthYear( String birthYear ) {
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }
    public String getDeathYear() {
        return deathYear;
    }
    public void setDeathYear( String deathYear ) {
        this.deathYear = deathYear;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription( String description ) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getHistory() {
        return history;
    }
    public void setHistory( String history ) {
        this.history = history;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).